# I need assistance to control loops and their conditions in javascript (underscore) to properly format array

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to create an array of objects that will be posted to a menu broken down by timeToEat and dayOfTheWeek. It should loop over each index in the daysOfWeek array, and if the dayOfTheWeek of the object (from the db) matches the index of the daysOfWeek ("tue" === "tue"), it should enter the the record in the proper slot.

**A record looks like this in the db:**

```
{ "timeToEat" : "amSnack", 
  "dayOfTheWeek" : "tue", 
  "onTheMenu" : "apples", 
  "_id" : "xTziTnHYmgh5obYDB" }
```

**The JS Method to find amSnacks in the mongoDB:**

```
amSnacks: function() {      
    var amSnacks = EatingTimes.find({timeToEat: "amSnack"}, {sort: {dayOfTheWeek: 1}}).fetch();
    var daysOfWeek = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri"];
    var NA = {onTheMenu: "N/A"};    
    var eatingTimes = [];

    _.each(daysOfWeek, function(day){
        _.each(amSnacks, function(amSnack){
            if (amSnack.dayOfTheWeek === day) {
                eatingTimes.push(amSnack);
            } else {
                eatingTimes.push(NA);
            }
        });
    });
    // console.log(eatingTimes);
    return eatingTimes;
   }
```

[image: just one all ok]

**If I add another record:**

{ "timeToEat" : "amSnack", 
  "dayOfTheWeek" : "tue", 
  "onTheMenu" : "apples", 
  "_id" : "xTziTnHYmgh5obYDB" }

{ "timeToEat" : "amSnack", 
  "dayOfTheWeek" : "fri", 
  "onTheMenu" : "cereal", 
  "_id" : "yebkabPurnyQjqb5u" }

[image: too many n/a entered]

**The console.log(eatingTimes):**

```
eatingTimes:  [
Object
onTheMenu: "N/A"
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
onTheMenu: "N/A"
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
onTheMenu: "N/A"
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
_id: "xTziTnHYmgh5obYDB"
dayOfTheWeek: "tue"
onTheMenu: "apples"
timeToEat: "amSnack"
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
onTheMenu: "N/A"
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
onTheMenu: "N/A"
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
onTheMenu: "N/A"
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
onTheMenu: "N/A"
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
_id: "yebkabPurnyQjqb5u"
dayOfTheWeek: "fri"
onTheMenu: "cereal"
timeToEat: "amSnack"
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
onTheMenu: "N/A"
__proto__: Object
]
```

You see that the formatting is all off if there are more than 1 record. How can I return an array that will just place the correct snack in the proper place if there is a match on dayOfTheWeek, and if there is no match, then push the NA for that specific weekday without creating too many NA entries?

Answer (score 0):

**Working Solution:**

```
amSnacks: function() {
    var amSnacks = EatingTimes.find({timeToEat: "amSnack"}, {sort: {dayOfTheWeek: 1}}).fetch();
    var daysOfWeek = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"];
    var eatingTimes = [];

    var i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < daysOfWeek.length; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < amSnacks.length; j++) {
            if (daysOfWeek[i] === amSnacks[j].dayOfTheWeek) 
                eatingTimes.push(amSnacks[j]);
        }

        var amSnacksArrayFromDb = [];

        _.map(eatingTimes, function(amSnack) {
            amSnacksArrayFromDb.push(amSnack.dayOfTheWeek);
        });

        var missingDaysOfWeek = _.difference(daysOfWeek, amSnacksArrayFromDb);

        var missingDaysNA = [];
        _.map(missingDaysOfWeek, function(day) {
            var NA = { dayOfTheWeek: day, onTheMenu: "N/A"};
            missingDaysNA.push(NA);
        });

        var eatingTimesArray = eatingTimes.concat(missingDaysNA);

        var finalAMSnackTimes = 
        _.sortBy(eatingTimesArray, function(amSnack){
            return amSnack.dayOfTheWeek;
        });
    }

    return finalAMSnackTimes;
},
```

Comment: the db records look like:

'{ "timeToEat" : "amSnack", 
  **"dayOfTheWeek" : "0"**,
  "onTheMenu" : "apples", 
  "_id" : "xTziTnHYmgh5obYDB" }'